# Enable GPS in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, android-permissions

l am try build ionic geolocation project on Android .l used Location Accuracy
plugin and Android Permissions .  Every things seem working alright, but [Android Permissions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions) is not working . i click on button geolocation to get permission to turn on GPS without leaving app , i have nothing shows ! . Only one error in console is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"code":-1,"message":"A request is already in progress"}
```

method location :

```
async location() {

  this.p.checkPermission(this.p.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then(
    result => {
      if (!result.hasPermission)
         this.la.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {
          console.log(canRequest)

          if(!canRequest) {
            // the accuracy option will be ignored by iOS
            this.la.request(this.la.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
              () => console.log('Request successful'),
              error => console.log('Error requesting location permissions', error)
            );
          }
        
        });
      else {
      }
    },e=>{
      alert("2"+e)

    })
}
```

Any idea please ?